# How to build a binary expression tree from a prefix notation?

Tags: algorithm

[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cVnH.png)    (  * (+ 1 2 3)  5)
Operator like *, + can have more than two operands.

Comment: maybe some kind of search? if only there was a tool to search the internet....

Comment: If you haven't done it yet, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make prefix notation with unbounded number of operands you should define some additional rules for open/close brackets (and that's not what prefix notation generaly does).

Simple parser will take operation, first operand and add other operands one by one. On each step just create new operation node, left operand will take previous (current) result, right operand will take newly fetched operand.

Continue up to the end of input or close bracket. Do not remove close bracket from input - it should be dealt with in open-close parse part, not in operation parse.

Taking operand is straightforward:

- "(" -> go deeper and parse subexpression up to ")".
- Different operation - > go deeper and parse sub expression.
- Same operation cam be simply ignored, but it's up to you.
- Constant (or variable if you have them) -> make operand subexpression.